# How do I show a conditional image based on variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a different image depending on the outcome of my JS app.

My HTML + JS looks as follows now.

```
                if (c == 2) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num + ' is a Prime number';
                var imageshown = "OptimusPrime.gif"
            }else{
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num + ' is NOT a Prime number';
                var imageshown = "Megatron.gif"
            }
        }        
    </script>
<div class="container">
   <form  id="contact" method="post">

        <h3>Prime-O-Tron</h3>
        <h4>Please fill in a number in the field below and press "Calculate" to see if it is a prime number or not.</h4>

        Please enter a number:
        <input type="number" id="num" name="num" min="0" />
        <input type="button" value="Find Prime Number" onclick="findPrime()" name="find" />
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="result"></div>
        <img src= imageshown>
```

But it is not displaying any image, no matter if the outcome is from the if or the else.

How would I embed a different image based on the outcome of my JS ?

Comment: Try placing that particular script after the `html` with `result` id. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: use show hide technique in js. you can easily track any html element and show or hide it. a little bit googling will help.

Comment: you can not use local variable like that. give id to img tag and set source in javascript. that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `src` instead of updating the variable's value. Also you might simplify like this:

```js
  if (c == 2) {
    msg = num + ' is a Prime number';
    imageshown = "OptimusPrime.gif"
  } else {
     msg = num + ' is NOT a Prime number';
     imageshown = "Megatron.gif"
  }

  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var img = result.nextElementSibling;

  result.textContent = msg;
  img.src = imageshown;
} // <--function closing
```

Comment: Works like a dream!

Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: @Ceesiebird Glad this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

> html

```
   <img id='img' src= imageshown>
```

> javascript

```
if (c == 2) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num + ' is a Prime number';
    var imageshown = "OptimusPrime.gif"
} else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num + ' is NOT a Prime number';
    var imageshown = "Megatron.gif"
}

document.getElementById('img').src = imageshown;
```

Comment: where are you getting result element? which is not there in your html.

Comment: @Sindhoor it's a `demo`,  you can just ignore `result` element,   Ceesiebird reference this element in the Question.